# Cert manager letsencrypt only accepting default value for certificate , ignoring duration and renewBefore

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cert-manager

I am creating certificate using cert-manager (1.6.3). But the issue is , duration and renewBefore is not taking my custom values  , instead it is taking the default value (90 days )

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: test-tls-com
  namespace: api
spec:
  issuerRef:
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  duration: 10h
  renewBefore: 1h
  commonName: "*.domain-name.in"
  dnsNames:
    - "*.domain-name.in"
  secretName: test-tls-wild
```

But when I describe the certificate I can see Renewal Time is not matching

```
kubectl -n api describe  cert test-tls-com

---

 Not After:               2022-08-14T15:30:38Z
  Not Before:              2022-05-16T15:30:39Z
  Renewal Time:            2022-08-14T13:30:38Z  <--it is not 1h renewal time
```

My cluster issuer looks like

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: xxx@gmail.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        digitalocean:
          tokenSecretRef:
            name: digitalocean-dns
            key: access-token
```

```
 kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"6b1d87acf3c8253c123756b9e61dac642678305f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:10:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.11", GitCommit:"38d3c1f3d5306401bcf39a71bad3b5a5106033d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-03-16T14:02:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Using the above configuration I am able to create certificate , but not sure why the Renewal Time is not matching with the duration and renewBefore

Answer (score 0):

Renewal Time is not matching with the duration and renewBefore because  The renewBefore and duration fields must be specified using a [Go time.Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseDuration) string format, which does not allow the d (days) suffix. You must specify these values using s, m, and h suffixes instead.

Duration and RenewBefore should be as below in the YAML file as prescribed by [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/certificate/#the-rotationpolicy-setting); then only it will match with renewal time and duration time.

Example :

duration: 2160h # 90d

renewBefore: 360h # 15d - custom dates we can give .